# MySQL LIKE search unable to find value in array

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, sql-like

I am building a Wordpress website and in a search.php file, I am trying to perform this MySQL query:

```
$boards_id = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT $wpdb->terms.term_id
    FROM $wpdb->terms, $wpdb->term_taxonomy, $wpdb->termmeta
    WHERE $wpdb->terms.name LIKE %s
    AND $wpdb->terms.term_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id
    AND $wpdb->terms.term_id = $wpdb->termmeta.term_id
    AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'board'
    AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.description != ''
    AND $wpdb->termmeta.meta_key = 'category'
    AND $wpdb->termmeta.meta_value LIKE '%Dads%'
    ORDER BY $wpdb->terms.name ASC
    LIMIT $limit, $boards_per_page"
    , '%' . get_search_query() . '%'
    )
);
```

The problem I am having is that this query condition is not working:

```
AND $wpdb->termmeta.meta_value LIKE '%Dads%'
```

In the MySQL structure, meta_value type is longtext. Each meta_value in the database contains arrays such as this one:

```
a:1:{i:0;s:4:"Dads";}
```

In my troubleshooting, the search ONLY yields the correct result if I change '%Dads%' to 'Dads' and change a:1:{i:0;s:4:"Dads";} in MySQL to just: Dads

Comment: Welcome on Stack Oveflow! It's a bit hard to read your code. It seems you're concatting everything (which is considered bad practise btw). If so, can you just post the *final* SQL query? Maybe there is something oviously wrong in there, but it's hard to tell. Also, please be more detailed when describing 'not correct results'. It could mean anything from one row too many to a fatal error in the script.

Comment: You're passing in a search parameter but don't have any placeholders. Are you sure that's why you're not getting any results?

Comment: Can you please echo/print your query and post the result in your question? Ie. echo "SELECT $wpdb->terms.term_id...". It would help to see what the DB engine is actually receiving. Thanks. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110266/how-to-print-the-excuted-sql-right-after-its-execution?answertab=votes#tab-top